# reading all <p> values within a <div> tag in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, tags

I am trying to read all values inside the paragraph:
Example

Page.ASPX

```
<div id="div1">

<p> text1 </p>
<p> text2 </p>
<p> text3 </p>

</div>
```

I would like to get values text1,text2,text3 in the server side code (C#).

By the way I need the div tag to never have runat="server".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for what? You want us to write code for you? We won't. If you have a specific issue with something you've written, post it and we'll help you solve it. Otherwise, best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks for what! I was trying to be as polite as I can, But It seems you was rude. The thing is I was trying but as I was saying that there is a solution using the runat , But I need this div to be client because I am using some jquery codes for the paragraphs. Any way thanks for rude comment.

Comment: What about having your P tags with the runat="server" or wrapping your div in another div that can have the runat="server"?

Comment: I tried this before and didn't work.     Thanks for your try.

Comment: I will try to store the texts in hidden fileds. I don't know whether its a good idea ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function call()
        {

            alert($("#div1").children(0).html());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery, JSON and a controller/code-behind. You're welcome in advance.

Comment: Couldn't get the paragraphs. Same thing I guess, I Always getting it empty. Thanks for your try.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use an HTTPWebRequest to get the HTML and use XPath to get those values.

Comment: Couldn't get the paragraphs. Same thing I guess, I Always getting it empty. Thanks for your try.

Comment: What do you mean "thanks for your try?". If you're not getting it via XPATH, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an element that is over first parent server side element in your page, for example place-holder or form element, you can parse (using HtmlAgiltyPack) its innerHtml in serverside. I mean something like this.

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(placeHolder.innerHtml);

var nodeToSplit = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p");
var lines = nodeToSplit.SplitIntoLines(3);

foreach (var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
```

You should modify this code for your own scenerio. I hope, This help.

Comment: Couldn't load the <p>, the paragraphs are generated at run time using jquery through append.   Thanks for your try.